# Will creating a Toast inside a Runnable cause a memory leak?

Tags: android, memory-leaks, runnable, toast

I use this portion of code, seen in many places, to push a *Toast* to the UI thread from a background thread:

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivityFragment.this.getActivity(), "My Message"
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
```

It works great. However, because *Runnable* is an anonymous inner class with an implicit reference to the *Fragment* or *Activity*, will it cause a memory leak to occur? Or is the lifespan of the *Toast* so short that it isn't a factor and will be garbage collected soon?

Comment: it won't after the run is executed

Answer (score 1):

> Or is the lifespan of the Toast so short that it isn't a factor and will be garbage collected soon?

You answered own question. It's potentially a "short-living" memory leak.